# compute Sobol first order index

Tags: python, statistics, stat

I am trying to compute `Sobol index` by myself using `python` but I am facing some problems. The formula is very simple however I don't understand some part :

[image]

Here, `E[Y|Qi]` denotes the expected value of the output Y when parameter Qi is fixed. The first order `Sobol sensitivity index` tells us the expected reduction in the variance of the model when we fix parameter `Qi`. The sum of the first order `Sobol sensitivity indices` can not exceed one.
In my case, I have already the output and inputs in a dataframe.
the first thing is about `E[Y|Qi]`, I dont know how to fix `Qi?` I tired this :

`

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(path)
tb = data['toa_tb_h'].values # the output 
sm = data['par_sm'].values # input
tau = data['par_tau'].values #input
ts = data['par.t_soil_surf'].values # input
c = data['par.c'].values # input
# compute E[tb|sm]
E[Y|Qi]
e_tb_per_sm = data.groupby("par_sm")["toa_tb_h"].mean()

si_sm = np.var(e_sm)/ np.var(tb)
```

I am not sure if what I am doing is correct, the problem is I find some time the is higher than `1` which is not correct.

I tried to compute the index based on the formula and expect to have results correct (less than 1)

Comment: Interesting question, however, I wonder if the formula is correct. If Q is entirely irrelevant, E[Y|Q_i] = E[Y] for all i, and Var[E[Y|Q_i]] is just the sample variance of E[Y], which is going to be something like Var[Y]/n where n is the number of data in the i'th subgroup, so S_i is going to be something like 1/n. That doesn't make much sense to me. Is it maybe supposed to be E[Var[Y|Q_i]]/Var[Y] ? You might consider taking up this question on stats.stackexchange.com to sort out the conceptual issues first.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! but Actually I am following the formula of Sobol Index, I also want to add that the aim is to know if Qi is relevant or no.